# Bug in a FB status window - iframe version

Tags: facebook, api, iframe

[Prnt screen of the problem](http://www.brandys-ve-svete.cz/screen.jpg)

Hi there, I need some advice. As you can see in the image, I have iframe on my website (width 220px) and space within the box is not fully used. I can see margin on the right side (red arrows), where the scroll bar is. 
I need to stretch out the content into the full width of the box. (Delete the space between the arrows)
Can I do something about that? Is that a FB bug?

THX for advices.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the word „labyrinth” would not really fit on the line where your arrows are – if so, then there’s no „bug” at all, it’s just automatic line breaking as is totally common in HTML displaying.